# 2 Issues with Codelite MinGW G++

Tags: winapi, c++11, linker, g++, mingw32

I'm using the latest version of codelite with the built in mingw 4.8.1 compiler/linker.

The first issue I have, when I create a new g++ project in Codelite with MinGW and then add the -mwindows flag to the linker build settings to utilize (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH), any cout statement I have in code doesn't print to the console. I need the -mwindows flag for GetStockObject to work, but I have no idea why it would break the cout statement. The code compiles and runs just fine, just nothing gets printed to the console.

The second issue I have is when I try to instantiate a basic class that is in a different project but still under the same workspace. The linker will give out an undefined reference error when I try to instantiate any class in the other project if I just link the .h class file in the project I'm working in. For example:

```
Framework *test = new Framework();
```

will give out

```
E:/CodeLite/ElysiumEngine/Main/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Framework::Framework()'
```

When I include this api.hpp file in the header:

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORKAPI_HPP
#define FRAMEWORKAPI_HPP

#include "Framework.hpp"

#endif // FRAMEWORKAPI_HPP
```

but the code links and runs just fine once I do this:

```
#ifndef FRAMEWORKAPI_HPP
#define FRAMEWORKAPI_HPP

#include "Framework.hpp"
#include "Framework.cpp"

#endif // FRAMEWORKAPI_HPP
```

I've never had to link the .cpp file in any other compiler or project I'm working on. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Is there anything I can do to solve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer to your 1st question:

The -mwindows flag causes the compiler to pass --subsystem,windows flag to the linker.

The linker flag --subsystem,windows causes your final executable to marked as a non-console (windowed) application and it also sets the default entry point to WinMainCRTStartup.

WinMainCRTStartup does not initialize console I/O and therefore anything printed/read at the console is ignored

Comment: Ok, it seems like there would be 2 solutions to the problem. Either set up my window structure so I don't need to pass the subsystem windows flag, or initialize the console I/O myself. So when I fill out the WNDCLASSEX window structure, what would I need to set WNDCLASSEX::hbrBackground so I don't need to use GetStockObject? Also, how do I initialize the console I/O so I can use it? This is going to be a D3D application, so I guess I should just figure out how to do the console I/O?

Comment: I found this link: http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/ And it shows how to open a console window.